# Windows.h Not Found, Why?

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk, ubuntu-11.10, speex

I am following [this](http://andrewbrobinson.com/2011/11/28/a-jni-wrapper-for-speex-on-android/) blog to set up JNI with android ndk on my box which runs ubuntu 11.10... In this program I am integrating speex with my existing application which streams the audio. So far everything was working fine but things destroyed as I integrated speex_echo_cancelation... Now I get following error... any help ?

```
jni/./libspeex/mdf.c:78:21: error: windows.h: No such file or directory
jni/./libspeex/mdf.c: In function 'speex_echo_cancellation':
jni/./libspeex/mdf.c:1195: error: invalid operands to binary + (have 'float' and 'spx_float_t')
jni/./libspeex/mdf.c:1216: error: invalid operands to binary + (have 'float' and 'spx_float_t')
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/speex/./libspeex/mdf.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Hello, your link is dead. is this at least similar to the original blog post? [http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1726](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1726)
Here is a more code-comprehensive question for a similar problem: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092415/speex-support-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092415/speex-support-in-android)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it's not finding windows.h because you're not on a Windows system.  It shouldn't be looking for windows.h because you're not targeting a Windows system.  Are you sure that you have downloaded the right package and that all of your environment variables set correctly?

Comment: +1 thanks that really helped, act I was using a previous version of  speex which was being used on windows machines....I replaced that with newer version and it compiled successfully.. Is their any way I can port that old code to android environment ? I have some old code which I don't want to change..

Comment: If they have kept their API the same then you should be able to port it without much trouble.  If not then no.